# Google's reCAPTCHA changing behaviour

Tags: recaptcha

I'm using Google's reCAPTCHA and sometimes it will display this
[image: reCPATCHA 2]

instead of this

[image: reCPATCHA 1]

This is really annoying because you have to solve it multiple time before you get the code to paste it into the empty field.
When I go into incognito mode then it will be normal again.

I'm am currentlich developing and testing on localhost. Could that be a reason of this behaviour? Because im using it too much?
Is there a way to avoid it?

Thanks. :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'hve found this on https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq

**Some users are not seeing the checkbox reCAPTCHA widget. What's happening?**
[image]

Is the reCAPTCHA widget in the above example what your users are seeing?

> In some cases, the end user's environment doesn't have the features to support the checkbox reCAPTCHA widget.  When this occurs, reCAPTCHA falls back to an alternative challenge

For solution I thinkg you should use below key for testing purpose in your `Localhost`

```
Site key: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI
Secret key: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe
```

Comment: I dont know what my users are seeing because it's different on every computer of mine. The normal state is that checkbox widget. But when I was implementing the registration and testing it mulpilte times then it fell back to the alternative challenge. But when I went into incognito mode of the browser then there will be the checkbox widget again.

So this seems to be normal, how I understand it. Maybe due to intensive use of a single user? Thanks for the hint with the testing keys, they should be helpful and I dont have to use my own keys during testing. (Even if it wasn't an automated test)